# touchend and target _blank not cooperating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios

because I have both image and link hover states, I am using a common piece of code to make sure that you don't need to tap twice to open a link on iOS. See down for code used.

However, I have noticed that when using a link now with target="_blank", it opens both in the parent as well as the new window. How can I prevent that from happening? Naturally I want the parent tab to remain on the current website.

Also, I've also noticed that the javascript seemed to have made tapping a little on the sensitive side, i.e. sometimes it already opens a link on the next page with only a single tap. Is this normal? Is there a solution for this?

```js
  $('a').on('click touchend', function(e) {
    var el = $(this);
    var link = el.attr('href');
    window.location = link;
 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use e.preventDefault(); to cancel native behavior and then use window.open(link, target); to open link in appropriate target:

```
$('a').on('click touchend', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var el = $(this);
    var link = el.attr('href');
    var target = el.attr('target');
    window.open(link, target); 

});
```

Comment: Thank you! So if I understand correctly it retains the behavior on touch-screen devices, and cancels it out on mouse-clicking devices? Also, do I understand correctly that I can after using this code just enter target="_blank" or do I need to incorporate some script into the link? (sorry am not very experienced with javascript)

Comment: on both iOS and regular browsers now all links open in a new window. I am trying to have only the ones that have the target _blank attribute open in a new window...

Comment: Use target="_self" attribute to open link in same tab.

Comment: Kostya, thank you so much! It works like a charm now. You're my hero today :-)